# generate pdf from form submit output file

Tags: php, html, api, pdf, input

Okay, this is driving me nuts and my deadline is tomorrow. 
I'm working on this very long html form and need to generate a PDF from the submitted inputs, preferably with PHP. 
I have already written an HTML that formats the inputs nicely, and if possible I would just like to parse this dynamic file into some sort of PDF generator API or SOMETHING, that takes the work off me. 
The thing works like this: The user enters his data into regular HTML input fields which are located in a huge `<form>`. The user then presses the `<submit>` button, which `<POST>`s the data to the `<action.php>` file.

```
<form id='kontakt_form' method='POST' action='app/tpl/form/action.php/' enctype='multipart/form-data'>

     <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

The `action.php` file looks kind of like this:

```
<h1>13.1 Does your company have a safety program?</h1>
<?php
    echo $_POST["safetyprogram"];
?>
```

Etc etc. So when you press `submit`, you get redirected to the `action.php` site, where all your submitted data is presented nicely.

Now is there an easy way to just take `action.php` and pass it to a PDF generator api or something like that?

All of the solutions I've found required me to rewrite the whole output file, which is a huge mountain of work.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php?page=Examples